# How to get more images in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api

15 images appear at the beginning from API, the get dogs button has the function of loading an additional 15 images (and so on), but it doesn't work. How to make the button work?

**http.service.ts** - service with API and HttpClient

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DogInfo } from '../interface/dogInfo';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HttpService {

  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: 'YOUR_KEY_HERE',
  });

  DOGS_FETCHED = 0;
  DOGS_TO_FETCH = 15;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchDogsFromApi(): Observable<DogInfo[]> {
    const page = (this.DOGS_FETCHED + this.DOGS_TO_FETCH) / this.DOGS_TO_FETCH - 1;

    const url = `https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds?page=${page}&order=desc&limit=${this.DOGS_TO_FETCH}`;

    return this.http.get<DogInfo[]>(url, { headers: this.httpHeaders })
      .pipe((response) => {
        this.DOGS_FETCHED += this.DOGS_TO_FETCH;
        return response;
      });
  }
}
```

**dogsList.component.ts** - fetching images from HttpService and getDogs function

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/service/http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dogsList',
  templateUrl: './dogsList.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dogsList.component.css']
})
export class DogsListComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  doggos: any = [];
  
  onFetchDogsFromApi(): any {
    this.httpService.fetchDogsFromApi().subscribe(
      (response) => this.doggos = response
    );
  }

  getDogs() {
    this.onFetchDogsFromApi();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.onFetchDogsFromApi();
  }
}
```

**dogsList.component.html** - list of images with ngFor directive

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="dogs">
        <div *ngFor="let item of doggos" >
            <p style="display: none;">{{item.id}}</p>
            <img src={{item.image.url}} ngClass="zoom-img" routerLink="/home/{{item.id}}" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" (click)="getDogs()">Get dogs</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you always override existing 15 images with the next 15 images.

Instead of overriding it, you should just add the next 15 images to the existing array. So, instead of this:

```
this.httpService.fetchDogsFromApi().subscribe(
  (response) => this.doggos = response
);
```

Do this:

```
this.httpService.fetchDogsFromApi().subscribe(
  (response) => this.doggos.push(...response)
);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Consider also accepting and upvoting my answer, so others with the same issue can see it worker for you.

Answer (score 0):

you always ask about the same URL.

Use

```
fetchDogsFromApi(page:number,limit:number): Observable<DogInfo[]> {
   const url = `https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds?page=${page}&order=desc&limit=${limit}`;
..
}
```

And call to your service as

```
this.page++;
this.onFetchDogsFromApi(this.page,10);
```

NOTE: It's better "control" the page from the component, not form the service

Comment: I don't think the same URL will be called each time, since the service's `DOGS_FETCHED` variable will be increased each time, which will call the next batch correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the `doggos` array with the new response as shown below.

```
this.httpService.fetchDogsFromApi().subscribe(
  (response) => this.doggos = [...this.doggos, ...response];
);
```